# iplocation.net Reports the Same Proxy, TorBrowser or Firefox (non-tor)

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, proxy, information-leaks, ip-address-leak, proxy-leaks

The site https://www.iplocation.net/find-ip-address  (What is my IP?) reports an IP address, and two proxy addresses.  One of the two proxy addresses is the same from TorBrowser or from Firefox (non-tor).  I tried this with two different VPNs, and from different VPN servers.  I haven't tried this without a VPN, as I only connect to Tor when using a VPN.   This doesn't seem okay.  I searched that IP address with Google, and I don't see any report of this, which I would expect if they showed that IP address as a proxy for everyone.

Comment: *[...] I only connect to Tor when using a VPN.* - why that?!? as already said thousand times: this may even harm your anonymity! - perhaps this is here the case... so please try Tor without a VPN (as it is supposed to work the best) and then we'll see.

Comment: Do you have a reference for that claim?  I am not using Tor-encryted VPN, which is available I am connecting to tor directly, and my machine is using a VPN.

Comment: its not a claim, its a fact (e.g. https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq#IsTorLikeAVPN)! anything else is just sales patter of people who want to sell a VPN... in most (to nearly all) cases Tor works the best either without anything else or connected through a [bridge](https://www.torproject.org/docs/bridges).

Answer (score 1):

**DO NOT USE A VPN WITH TOR**

This has been documented to be a *very* bad idea. The VPN will track *everything* you do, and destroy your anonymity.

Just connect directly to Tor, and if needed to access Tor, use bridges